# How to stop collectionCloning while adding a failed instance in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to stop collection cloned even when all the data is restored on recovered instance using oplog replay.

Replication Scenario
    I have a 3 node Replcation set up. 
Load 
    There is continous load, data keeps adding every day.
and we have oplog backups every 2 housrs. Inspite of the oplog backups set for ever 2 hours,
we have some of transactions roll off from the oplog. That means we might be miss some records when we replay those oplogs.

Scenario.
In a replication scenario we have one of the secondaries not responding and by the time we join it back to the replication set
the minimum oplog timestamp goes past the oplog in the failed instance and the failed instance tries to catch up but it gets into a recovering mode.
from the 
log message on the recovering instance.

```
2019-02-13T15:49:42.346-0500 I REPL     [replication-0] We are too stale to use primaryserver3:27012 as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: Timestamp(1550090168, 1) is before their earliest timestamp: Timestamp(1550090897, 28907) for 1min until: 2019-02-13T15:50:42.346-0500
2019-02-13T15:49:42.347-0500 I REPL     [replication-0] sync source candidate: primaryserver3:27012
2019-02-13T15:49:42.347-0500 I ASIO     [RS] Connecting to primaryserver3:27012
2019-02-13T15:49:42.348-0500 I REPL     [replication-0] We are too stale to use primaryserver3:27012 as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: Timestamp(1550090168, 1) is before their earliest timestamp: Timestamp(1550090897, 22809) for 1min until: 2019-02-13T15:50:42.348-0500
2019-02-13T15:49:42.348-0500 I REPL     [replication-0] could not find member to sync from
```

To bring this instance at par with Primary,  We make this "RECOVERING" instance as a "new PRIMARY" and apply all oplog backups taken till present insert. after the oplogs are applied Record count on both the servers match. Now when i join the recovering instance(ie "new PRIMARY") back to the replication set, 
i see the logs showing "initial sync" which is supposed to do and then seeing the below log

```
2019-03-01T12:11:58.327-0500 I REPL     [repl writer worker 4] CollectionCloner ns:datagen_it_test.test finished cloning with status: OK
2019-03-01T12:12:40.518-0500 I REPL     [repl writer worker 8] CollectionCloner ns:datagen_it_test.link finished cloning with status: OK
```

Where the collections are cloned again. 
My question is Why does it clone again to get the data. We have the data restored in the "recovering" instance records all match.
How to stop the cloning happening.

Comment: How did you manually restored the data to the recovery node? Did you run it as a standalone instance or a replica set node?  After the manual restoration of data, did you compare the oplog entries both the nodes? Are they in sync?

Comment: yes i created as a standalone Primary instance and applied oplogs. i did not check the oplog entries as we have applied till the last oplog backup. The data are all in sync.

Comment: Check your oplog entries are in sync are not? Also, if there are any other CRUD operations happening in replica set in the mean time , the node will again go to recovery mode to catch up the new op lo g entries.

Answer (score 1):

As per the MongoDB documentation

> A replica set member becomes “stale” when its replication process
>   falls so far behind that the primary overwrites oplog entries the
>   member has not yet replicated. The member cannot catch up and becomes
>   “stale.” When this occurs, you must completely resynchronize the
>   member by removing its data and performing an initial sync.
>
> This tutorial addresses both resyncing a stale member and creating a
>   new member using seed data from another member, both of which can be
>   used to restore a replica set member. When syncing a member, choose a
>   time when the system has the bandwidth to move a large amount of data.
>   Schedule the synchronization during a time of low usage or during a
>   maintenance window.
>
> MongoDB provides two options for performing an initial sync:
>
> Restart the mongod with an empty data directory and let MongoDB’s
>   normal initial syncing feature restore the data. This is the more
>   simple option but may take longer to replace the data.
>
> See Automatically Sync a Member.
>
> Restart the machine with a copy of a recent data directory from
>   another member in the replica set. This procedure can replace the data
>   more quickly but requires more manual steps.
>
> See Sync by Copying Data Files from Another Member.

Step by step procedure is available in

[Resync a Member of a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#procedures)